# Memory reservation for java objects

Tags: java, c++, memory

I know that when declaring object instances in c++ like so:

```
Object object
```

the Object constructor is called and memory is provided for that object, however i find that when you do this in java the object instance doesn't have a value until:

```
object = new Object()
```

is written. I want to know specifically when memory is provided for the object. I thought that both construction and the new keyword allocated memory so `Object object = new Object()` seems redundant. I read on oracle's site that declaration "reserves" memory and new "allocates" memory, I would like to know what is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the space required for the *variable* and the space required for the *object*. Bear in mind that the value of the variable is just a reference - very much like a pointer in C++. So if you have:

```
Object x = null;
```

then the variable `x` itself takes up enough space for a reference (usually 4 or 8 bytes). Now if you have:

```
x = new Object();
```

that creates an object - the value of `x` is now a reference to the newly created object. `x` itself takes up the same amount of space as before, but there's also the space required for the object itself (basically the fields, a reference for the type of the object, and data for synchronization and house-keeping).

Answer (score 2):

When you do something like

```
Object object = new Object()
```

in Java, object is a reference to the actual instance on the managed heap. Compared to C++, that's roughly doing

```
Object* object=new Object()
```

So when you do

```
Object object;
```

in Java, a place is created for the 'reference' to a instance. 
Similar to

```
Object* object;
```

in C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object foo=null;
```

in meaning of C++ creates reference foo to the object of class Object. So, it consumes memory for reference only.

```
Object realFoo=new Object();
```

creates such reference and also real object with whatever is with this object. So, it is memory for the reference and object itself.

In Java there is no memory reservation - only memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

declaration reserves memory: parameters and variables inside a method will have memory reserved for them in the stackframe.

allocates memory: at runtime, when executing "new", memory will be allocated for the new Object on the heap

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that in Java, `Object object` is simply a **reference** to an `Object` called `object`. If you're familiar with C++, you can think of this reference as a pointer (though it's not quite the same).

On a 64-bit machine, the `object` reference is 8 bytes. When you actually instantiate an `Object` using the `new` keyword and assign it to the reference, this is where memory is allocated for your `Object`.